# URL rewrite fails: Internal redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m trying to rewrite `example.com/test` to `example.com/pages/test.php` (and so on).

I’ve made this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) /pages/$1.php
```

This does not work: Apache gives me this error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I have no idea how to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is rewriting `/test` to `/pages/test.php`, then trying to rewrite it to `/pages/pages/test.php.php`, then `/pages/pages/pages/test.php.php.php` and so on...

Add a [L] flag to stop rewriting after the first.

In general, you also want a couple of Rewrite conditions as follows to prevent rewrites that you don't actually want rewritten (for images, scripts, etc.):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /pages/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looping. Try to add [L] at the end of the RewriteRule.